# DRF Serializer `source` in extra_kwargs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting a weird exception while trying to save the data via DRF using `source` key in `extra_kwargs`. Basically, I want to accept the request data using a different key from the model field.

**My Models.py**

```
class UserWishlist(models.Model):

    wishlist_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, db_index=True, related_name='user_wishlist',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class WishlistProducts(models.Model):

    wishlist = models.ForeignKey(
        UserWishlist, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )  ######## this is the model field that I want to `source` in `extra_kwargs`.

    product_id = models.UUIDField(blank=True, null=True)

    product_url = models.URLField()

    shop = models.ForeignKey(
        Shops, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    ) #### This also. But this works fine.
```

**My Serializer.py**

```
class WishlistProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta(object):
        """Meta."""
        model = WishlistProducts
        fields = ('wishlist_id', 'product_id', 'product_url', 'shop_id',
                  'created_at', 'updated_at')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'shop_id': {'source': 'shop'}, ###### NOT AN ISSUE
            'wishlist_id': {'source': 'wishlist'}, ####### ISSUE
        }
```

**My action method in views.py**

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
def add_products(self, request):
    serializer = WishlistProductSerializer(
        data=request.data, context={'request': request}
    )
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
```

POST API call on the above view/serializer with below data:

```
{
  "wishlist_id": "51bb119e-b30a-42e6-ac5b-2608a96aafec",
  "product_id": "3fa85f61-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "product_url": "https://googl1e.com",
  "shop_id": "ffa34976-b82a-469e-b077-83f8962ed34f"
}
```

When the POST request is fired, I get a `KeyError at /wishlist/add_products/ 'wishlist'`. If I remove the `source` from extra_kwargs for `wishlist` (and replace `wishlist_id` to `wishlist` in `Meta.fields`, the complete flow works.

Interestingly, I don't get the KeyError for mentioning `shop_id` as the source field of `shop`.

What am I missing?

Comment: btw what the error message?

Comment: `KeyError at /wishlist/add_products/ 'wishlist'`

Comment: The issue was with the library. Updating to its latest version, solved the issue.